# How do I capture MouseWheel events in a UserControl?

Tags: .net, winforms, scroll, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` derived control. When the user moves the mouse wheel I'd like to capture that and respond to it.

I've tried using the `Scroll` event but that doesn't ever seem to fire which I'm guessing is because my control doesn't have (or need) a scroll bar.

I can't find the `MouseWheel` event in Windows Forms Designer although [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel(v=vs.80).aspx) suggest it should be part of every `Control` derived element. Again, [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggest the `UserControl` is a derivative, so it should support the event.

What am I missing?

Comment: The WM_MOUSEWHEEL message is sent to the window that has the focus.  That will never be your UserControl, it cannot get the focus.  The basic reason the event is hidden in the designer.  It will be a control inside the UC.  Only if it doesn't handle the message does it get passed to the parent.  We can't guess what controls you put in your UC or where the focus is located from your question.

Comment: My UserControl has no controls in it - it just handles the `OnPaint` even to do some drawing. I've looked in the parent `System::Windows::Forms::Form ` and that doesn't appear to have a MouseWheel event either. From what you're saying, the parent would currently be handling the event?

Comment: Have you considered instead inheriting from a `PictureBox` (or similar) if you're not using your `UserControl` as a container for other controls?

Comment: No I hadn't. Would that help?

Comment: There is no point at all in using a UC if you don't put any controls in it.  Just derive your class from Control instead.  Now it *can* get the focus and *does* have a MouseWheel event.  Don't use a PictureBox, it can't get the focus either.  Make sure that the user can tell your control has the focus, you need to draw a focus rectangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else faces this, in the end I simply added some handling in the 
parent control to call functionality in the user control:

```
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MouseWheel += gcnew MouseEventHandler(this, &Form1::MouseWheelHandler);
    }

    void MouseWheelHandler(Object^ sender, MouseEventArgs^ e)
    {
        m_myUserControl->MouseWheel(e->Delta);
    }
```

Comment: I am not understanding this. If forms have a `MouseWheel` event. Why don't they show up in the list of events?

Comment: They are hidden from the designer for some odd reason.

Answer (score 2):

A solution to get mouse events from UserControls is to set the Background of the control. Every panel (Grid, Canvas, ...) need a Backgroundcolor to get mouse events handled.

So just add a transparent background to your control and the scroll events are captured

```
Background="Transparent"
```